# Am I using a validation dataset if I just feed a dataset to my Keras model?

Tags: python, keras

So my question is about the `fit` function and what happens if I just feed a dataset to it like we can see below:

```
trainDataset = train_parsed_image_dataset.map(buildInputsLabels).shuffle(2000).batch(batches)
history = model.fit(trainDataset, epochs=epochs)
```

What does the model use as validation dataset? Does it not use any validation dataset? I know that i can specifically tell what I want to use for validation but in this case, where I feed only a dataset what happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first of all, you must split your dataset into x and y. x is the input and y is the output. if you don't set the validation parameter then your model isn't going to do any tuning since there is no validation set.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Although I believe I do not have to separate my dataset. I really do not understand why tho.

Comment: are you doing a classification task? if so then you must separate your dataset. if you are doing some clustering then maybe you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't define `validation_split` > 0 ([the default is 0](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method)), it will **not** use any validation data. It will use the same training data to evaluate `loss` & `accuracy`. This may lead to overfitting.

Reference: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2279

Comment: or `validation_data=[X_test, y_test]`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will soon try this! Thanks! Also if you could, why there is no need for me to split the data in x and y? I just know it works without me having to, not sure why

Comment: Because in your code you're passing `tf.data.Dataset` instance which already included both x (features) and y (labels) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! And can i feed a dataset to 'validation_data=' just like I do for trainning? Like having a validationDataset and feeding it into validation_data=validationDataset , being this validationDataset made by both features and labels?